# Distance function to SURF-128 descriptors comparing

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection, surf, feature-descriptor

I read that euclidean distance is not optimal for high dimensional data, but in [this](http://www.vision.ee.ethz.ch/~surf/eccv06.pdf) publcation is written that euclidean or manhattan distance should be used.
But what better? Any benchmarks, tests?
Is it possible to obtain absolute threshhold (I know about 0.7 ratio between nearest neighbors in knn search)?

Comment: I think that 64 dimension is not _high dimensional_ data. Fisher vectors or other descriptors have actually thousands dimensions.

Comment: @Mike SURF-128 descritors, I updated title. Ok, maybe dimension not very high, but question still interesting for me.

Comment: SURF has 64 dimensions, 128 is the _extended_ version. It doesn't change much, however :D